# xss-lock turns the screen black before running the lockscreen script

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting, i3, xlock

In my i3 config I have this line to lock the screen using i3lock.

```
exec --no-startup-id xss-lock --transfer-sleep-lock -- ~/scripts/lockscreen.sh
```

The script checks if I am watching YouTube or something like that and skips the lock-screen if so, and runs this line

```
xset s reset
```

This causes the screen to turn black for a brief moment before coming back.
How can I avoid this brief black screen?

This doesn't happen if I use xautolock because I can give it a timer to run the script, but I am trying to use xss-lock.